# jQuery swipe doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

I'm using jQuery 1.9.2. I've been trying to add swiping functionality to my app, but nothing I do works. On Google's mobile emulator, nothing happens when I swipe. What am I missing?

Here's the most vanilla example I could think of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('html').on("swipeleft",function() {
    $('html').html("");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: @SterlingArcher I'm not too familiar with the js console, but it doesn't say anything related to this on page load, and nothing in it happens when I swipe either.

Comment: jquery by itself doesn't have touch gestures built in. You need to add a plugin like the popular hammer js  -- http://hammerjs.github.io .. and its better if you $(document).on("swipeleft" .. rather than html

Comment: @Tasos Are you sure? It's defined in the jQuery mobile API: https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipeleft/. Doesn't that mean that it's built into jQuery mobile at least?

Comment: Change "i''m using jQuery 1.9.2" to '"I'm using Jquery Mobile (version)".

Comment: @Tasos Wait, I though jQuery mobile was just built into jQuery.. Is that something I have to separately require?